# pivoting Gridview in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

My Gridview Results comes in following the format:-

[image]

But I need output in following format:-

[image]

Stops should increase automatically (i.e. if there are  4 stops, it should show 4 stops in the Grid View).

My Gridview Code:-

```
  <asp:GridView ID="grdFlightInfo" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="AirlinesName" HeaderText="AirlinesName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="TotalNetFare" HeaderText="NetFare" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Stops" HeaderText="Stops" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As you want to load columns based on returned results, so you need to dynamically create columns. You have already defined the columns, so delete them.

After you get the results in tabular format (as you want to do in 2nd pic) either from database or by arranging the data in code behind, you just need to bind that to `GridView` directly.

If you do so, you need to set `AutoGenerateColumns="true"`.

Comment: Can't I do this using Boundfield? I am not using Database I am getting Data from Datatable.

Comment: Actually, according to the second pic, it is clear that, you need to bind dynamic columns and I thought of database from that. As you said, you are not having database, so you can define BoundFields for each Airline so that it becomes one one column. Then bind the Data to it accordingly.

Comment: Airlines are coming dynamically from XML. Then from XML I am creating Datatable and binding that datatable to GridView.

Comment: Yes, so that's why I said you to bind it directly to the GridView by assigning it to the DataSource. Then call DataBind. Set AutoGenerateColumns = "true". If your DataTable will look same as the 2nd pic, then GridView would show the same structure as well.

Comment: Can you help me with the code how can I make my DataTable in that structure?

Comment: I can't write code now as I don't have the system and environment. I can guide you. Just manipulate with data and create DataColumns, DataRows etc. so that it forms that structure.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using DataSource with your dataGrid you can use *DataBinding* Event

```
OnDataBinding
```

here you can write your custom code to increment according to the stops number

there is a good article on Codeproject that describes how to do this in details

[A Detailed Data Binding Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24656/A-Detailed-Data-Binding-Tutorial)

[Also on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/fbk67b6z%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)